# SAML 2.0 and OAUTH 2.0 Service Provider

Tags: oauth-2.0, saml-2.0

I have a *Service Provider* hosting web applications. 
These applications are protected by a *J2EE filter*, deployed in the Service Provider, that intercepts requests and communicate with *SAML 2.0 identity providers*.
Now the same service provider have to host even *Oauth 2.0* resources (so became an *Oauth 2.0 resource server*).

How can I evolve my *J2EE filter* to detect which requests have to be protected via *SAML 2.0* and which requests *via Oauth 2.0* *access_token* ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need to protect the web urls/services using this filter.So in that case you can filter the requested resource depending on context e.g. requests for url or service with context /X/department/finance/* with SAML and may be /X/department/hr/* using OAuth.

If the resources are also the same you can do an identification based on request parameter sent by client.

Comment: Thanks Yusuf. Probably I'll evaluate a combination of both your solutions as i have to provide both Rest API Oauth than web applications.